# translating between cents and dollars in html input in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm in a bit of a weird situation, I am dealing with currency in my we app. On the model side, I am saving currency as cents before sending to the server as I don't want to deal with decimal points on the server side.
In the view however, I want the to display normal currency and not cents.

So, I have this input field where I take the data from dollars and change it to cents:

```
<input name="balance" type="number" step="0.01" min="0"
    placeholder="Balance in cents" onChange={this.handleUpdate}
    value={this.props.user.balance / 100} />
```

And when there's a change in the input value, I change it back to cents before sending it upstream:

```
handleUpdate: function(e) {
  
  var value = e.target.value;
  
  // changing it back from cents to dollars
  value = parseFloat(value) * 100;
  
  // save back to the parent component managing the prop
  this.props.onUserUpdate(value);
  
}
```

This puts me in kind of a deadlock, there's no way for me to enter a decimal point "." Let me demonstrate :

1. `33` in the input box --> becomes `3300` in the parent state --> goes back as `33` in component prop - **all good**
2. `33.3` in the input box --> becomes `3330` in the parent state --> goes back as `33.3` in the component prop - **all good**
3. `33.` in the input box --> becomes `3300` in the parent state --> goes back as `33` in the component prop - **this is the problem**

As you can see in case #3, when the user first enters "." this doesn't translate back to the same number with "."

Since it's a controlled input, there's basically no way of writing "."

I have tried using uncontrolled element with `defaultValue`, but the amount prop is not ready the time the component is rendered so it's just empty

http://jsfiddle.net/fpbhu1hs/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Controlled inputs using derived values can be tricksy - if you need to be able to display invalid or otherwise weird input then...

1. always hold the input's `value` in its component's own `state`

   ```
   <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleUpdate} // rest as above...
   ```
2. derive the initial `value` in `getInitialState()`

   ```
   getInitialState: function() {
     return {value: this.props.user.balance / 100}
   }
   ```
3. implement `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to detect when the prop's value is changing from above and re-derive the state value

   ```
   componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
     if (this.props.user.balance != nextProps.user.balance) {
       this.setState({value: nextProps.user.balance / 100})
     }
   }
   ```

Now when the user enters "33.", you store their literal input using `setState()`, then call back to the parent.

```
handleUpdate: function(e) {
  var value = e.target.value
  this.setState({value: value})
  this.props.onUserUpdate(parseFloat(value) * 100)
}
```

If the value the parent then passes back down to the child via props hasn't changed (`3300 == 3300` in this case), then `componentWillReceiveProps()` won't do anything.

Working snippet:

```html
<script src="http://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.12.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">void function() { 'use strict';

var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {cents: 3300}
  },
  
  _changeValue() {
    this.setState({cents: Math.round(Math.random() * 2000 + Math.random() * 2000)})
  },

  _onCentsChange(cents) {
    this.setState({cents})
  },

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p><strong>Cents:</strong> {this.state.cents.toFixed(0)} <input type="button" onClick={this._changeValue} value="Change"/></p>
      <Child cents={this.state.cents} onCentsChange={this._onCentsChange}/>
    </div>
  }
})

var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {dollars: this.props.cents / 100}
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.cents != nextProps.cents) {
      this.setState({dollars: nextProps.cents / 100})
    }
  },

  _onChange(e) {
    var dollars = e.target.value
    this.setState({dollars})
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(dollars)) && isFinite(dollars)) {
      this.props.onCentsChange(parseFloat(dollars) * 100)
    }
  },

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" value={this.state.dollars} onChange={this._onChange}/>
    </div>
  }
})

React.render(<Parent/>, document.querySelector('#example'))

}()</script>
```

Comment: Very nice ! Thinking React does require some adjustments... Thanks you !

Comment: Your example works with React 0.14.0 https://jsfiddle.net/7h5o97wL/ but not working React 15.4.2 https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/73775/

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this simple solution to handle controlled inputs and decimal values.

1. Create two props in your state, one to hold actual value and another to hold string.

   ```
   constructor(props) {
       ....

       this.state = {
           myProperty: 1.42,
           myPropertyString: '1.42'
       }
   }
   ```
2. Set your input value to String one

   ```
   <input type="text"
          onChange={this.handleUpdate}
          value={this.state.myPropertyString}/>
   ```
3. In **handleUpdate** method update both state variables.

   ```
   handleUpdate(e) {
       this.setState({
           myProperty: parseFloat(e.target.value),
           myPropertyString: e.target.value
       });
   }
   ```