# Failed to parse "4." to 4

Tags: reactjs, input, redux, react-redux

I am working in React-redux and creating a number type field. The **event.target.value** returns a string, since it is number type editor it must return value as number so I parse the value to number. The problem comes when I try to enter **4.5**  . Firstly, when I type 4 it will get parsed into 4 (sting to number). But when the **.** entered the number **4.** get parse into **4**  , so I just failed to enter the floating point values.

> let onChangeText = (value)=> {
>         fieldProps.onChange(parseFloat(value));
>          }

If I parse the value in **onBlur** then it will work but for state management I have to work on **onChange** . Is there any way to parse **4.** string  to **4.** number .

Comment: have you looked at toFixed? `+ parseFloat('4.5').toFixed(2)`

Comment: Why do you think that "4" and "4." are, *as numbers*, different things that can be distinguished in any way?

Comment: @hobbs Hear hear!

Comment: what I am entering is  string and what I am saving is Number , which in results come back to input but without the "." .

Comment: @JohnRuddell toFixed also returns string value

Comment: @shubham... look closer at my comment. im converting it to a float.. via the `+`

Comment: Html input type='number' handles this itself . It does not pass '.' to onChange untill the number after the point get enter.
Like for" 4." it gives 4 as event.target.value and when the input got the value from state , that will be only 4 (without the point) but it will show point itself .

Comment: @JohnRuddell you are doing it with 4.5 , but my problem was with "4."

Comment: Can you post your entire component? I have this working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1101/

Comment: @shubham `4.` is not a valid number. likewise `4.00000` is `4`... if you need to display a fixed number of decimals then use `toFixed()`. In terms of functionality you are not going to have an invalid number. `4` and `4.` and `4.0` are the same thing. when you use something like `4.1` then your function will receive a float.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Please read the question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store user's literal input in your state and then apply the desired logic and store the result separately in the state of a parent element?

Here is a potential approach: [translating between cents and dollars in html input in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072727/translating-between-cents-and-dollars-in-html-input-in-react/28077112#28077112)

Comment: <input type="text" value={this.state.value}
             onChange={this.handleInput.bind(this)} />

not if you type '4.' the handleInput set the value 4 to data . This is what going in my case

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct but html input type=number giving it for no work . You should try that , But for dollar type symbols , this is best one .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onBlur` instead of `onChange`. Another benefit of this approach is that you reduce the amount of Redux actions; instead of firing an action on every keypress, you fire an action when the user is finished inputting data.

This will also require using `defaultValue` instead of `value` to link your component to the data. So the component would look something like this:

```
<input type="number" defaultValue={this.props.value} onBlur={onChangeText} />
```

This means the action will only trigger when your user has finished typing input, and blurred the input element.

Comment: I have mentioned in question that I have to use onChange