# React controlled number input jumps when deleting decimal point

Tags: reactjs

I have a controlled number input in a React app, and when I remove all the digits right of the decimal point, the decimal point itself is removed. So when I have `1.1`, and remove the rightmost 1, it should leave `1.`; but the point is also removed automatically, leaving `1`, and the cursor is moved to the front.

For a minimal example, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sashee/e00s7h9d/ . Just press backspace on the input to observe the behavior.

After some googling, I think the root of the problem is that `1.` is treated as `1`, and there is no way to extract the current value from the input.

Therefore, when I remove the rightmost 1, the following happens:

- The change handler is called
- The value is 1
- React updates the value in the state to 1
- The input now has the value of 1, instead of 1.

As I see, this is not a bug, but a weird outcome of the architecture. Are there any workarounds that use number inputs? Or should I fall back to regular text inputs?

**Update**:

It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in React itself, see [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/7359).

It is fixed from 15.5.4 onwards, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sashee/05qf5w7e/):

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.5.4/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.5.4/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you would like to have that decimal in place when you delete the number proceeding the decimal point? This isn't so much as a React question as it is more a general HTML one. Like you mention, if you would like the decimal point to show when you are inputing a number, then you can change the `type="number"` to `type="text"`.

Also, I'd like to point out that in your initial state, you are setting the value to a string, and then the string `"1.1"` is being coerced into the number `1.1`. For consistency you should set the initial state to a number if your input is `type="number"` or keep the initial state as a string and change the input to `type="text"`

If you would like the number in the box to increment or decrement by 0.1 every time the up or down arrow are pressed, change the `step` to `step="0.1"`.

Comment: Actually, the e.target.value returns strings, and not numbers, so it's consistent.

One possible use case for this is to change 1.1 to 1.25 .In this case I click at the end, delete the last 1, and enter 25. But as the number I'm editing changes, I can't do it.

Comment: Oh I see the issue now, I apologize I misunderstood the problem. I believe this question provides good insight to the OP's problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672804/failed-to-parse-4-to-4?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're defining your `input` as `type="number"` but the value you're throwing into it a string. When the string `"1."` gets converted to a number, it loses the decimal value.

```
// Example of string "1." getting converted to a number
parseInt("1.", 10) // 1
```

How to fix:

As @Yo Wakita says in his answer, just use a string input. However! You can easily disallow non-numbers with a RegEx:

```
_onChange(e) {
  // This will match all signed/unsigned floats
  // Pattern credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16951568/2518231
  // You'll probably want to store this as a default prop so that it isn't generated on every onChange
  var regex = new RegExp(/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/);

  if (regex.test(e.target.value) ) {
    this.setState({val: e.target.value})
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, only numbers are allowed.');
  }
},
```