# React onChange is swallowing my decimal when using parseFloat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsefloat, setstate

I have a simple onChange which takes  the user's input pareses it and sets the state to render. Here is the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      random: {
        foo: 0
      }
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
    let random = this.state.random;
    random[e.target.name] = parseFloat(e.target.value);
    this.setState({random});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} type="text" name="foo" value={this.state.random.foo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What I don't understand is where my decimal is going. I know there is no validation in place to stop the user from entering letters, but this is just a sample app to test this issue I ran into. When I enter a decimal point in does not get rendered. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does `e.target.value` show in the console?

Comment: before parsing or after?

Comment: ok just tried and got this. When I had just 1. I saw 1. in the console but not on the screen. When I wrote 1.2 I saw 12 in the console and the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [translating between cents and dollars in html input in React](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072727/translating-between-cents-and-dollars-in-html-input-in-react)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that React's `onChange` doesn't behave like the browser's `onChange` It behaves like `onInput` So it is getting called every time you type a value. This results in your `parseFloat` actually parsing `1.` instead of `1.2` and the parsed value of `1.` is `1`

Answer (score 2):

As other have said, the problem is that the number type doesn't hold enough information about the state of the input, so when `1.` makes a round trip it loses the `.`.

In other words, an input is a widget for editing a string, and your state doesn't contain enough information to recreate that string correctly, and instead the decimal point gets lost.

Thus, one solution is to store it as a string in your state, perhaps called `inputValue`. Then, using unidirectional data flow, manage the translation between that string and the parts of code that think of it numerically very explicitly. Converting from a string to a number is dangerous -- not every string represents a number, so that part of the code needs to deal with validation (and not lose track of the text input). And converting from a number to a string is risky, as you've already observed, so it should only be done when there is a good reason (for instance, the server is pushing an event that the data changed somewhere else, swap it out).

Answer (score 1):

The onChange event happens anytime you hit a key, which causes the function to run and parseFloat takes away `.` from your number, and that's why you end up having 12 instead of 1.2, so before using parseFloat you need to check whether the last character is `.` and add it back afterwards.

Comment: [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) doesn't take a base parameter.

Comment: This is how it's done in React. Google React controlled component

Comment: @Armin if you fix your answer I could take off my downvote

Comment: @nafg Done, how does it look?

Answer (score 0):

Change your default state to `foo: 1.11` - you will be able to edit this value (It isn't solution it is clue).

The problem here is `parseFloat` which is trims dot from end of string when you typing new float value, and return for your string `parseFloat('0.')` value `0`, hence you see your behavior...